# Getting java Connect exception while sending HTTPS request in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to send one HTTPS Sampler Request.  Getting the following while running

Thread Name: MCAB-UK 1-1
Sample Start: 2017-11-01 17:08:44 IST
Load time: 21597
Connect Time: 21597
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2463
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2463
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect

Response headers:

HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Comment: Check your port is correct and server is available in HTTPS

Comment: Yes, it is working when we use any REST client. It is working

Comment: What's your JMeter version? Did you try latest 3.3?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of HTTP Request  ?

Comment: Try doing a [telnet](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/utelnet.htm) and see if you can access the port from the same server where the jmeter runs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are hitting a website that is behind a proxy.

Did you configure the enterprise proxy for JMeter as per this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

Another possibility is you're using the wrong port or wrong scheme (http instead of https)